# Is it possible to use iterated values as method argument values?

Tags: loops, python-3.x, methods, iterator, arguments

I am working in Blender and Python 3.x.

I would like to use the iterated values of:

```
list(itertools.product([0,1,2,3], repeat = 3))

>>> [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), ... (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

(64 total products/permutations) And insert their respective values, one set at a time, into the following method:

```
def vid(h,j,k):
    m = h
    s = j
    b = k
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with some form of a loop so that, say, (0, 0, 0) can be inserted into (h, j, k), over and over again, until all 64 products/permutations have been inserted?

Apologies if this seems like a silly set of questions or is in any way unclear. Just starting out here on the ol' stack and I am rather stuck on this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture the return values of `vid` in a iterator, you could use [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
itertools.starmap(vid, itertools.product([0,1,2,3], repeat = 3)))
```

or (for a list) you could call `list` on the iterator, or use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[vid(*tup) for tup in itertools.product([0,1,2,3], repeat = 3)]
```

If you simply wish to call `vid` for each tuple, you could use a `for-loop`:

```
for tup in itertools.product([0,1,2,3], repeat = 3):
    vid(*tup)
```

Comment: thank you kindly! i used the last of your suggestions and it works perfectly!